# Error in adding QTabWidget to QDialog

Tags: qt, qt4.8, qtabwidget

I am trying to create UI like.. [image: UI]

for this created a subclass from QDialog and trying to add Menubar and Tabwidget via QVBoxLayout, I am able to add MenuBar successfully, but when I add Tabwidget ..

```
TabWidget = new QTabWidget();
TabWidget->addTab(new QWidget(),tr("Tab 1"));
VerticalLayout->addWidget(TabWidget);
```

Getting a runtime error as "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library 
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application support team for more information" with OK button.

and when I Use debugger it gives the error "Signal Received, The inferior stopped because it received a signal from Operating system"

could someone help me out to fix this problem ?

I am using Qt 4.8.1 in Qt Creator 2.4.1 in win 7

Thanks,

Comment: the code you have shown does not contain any significant error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ... It was my mistake that, not calling a method which initialising the TabWidget object.